# Javascript adding and deleting class wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i tried to build show and hide navigation to save more space. but after all i did, it became so jumpy. i can delete the show class and adding the the hide class but after that the hide class do nothing. please help.

```
<script>
    $(".servicesShowLink").click(function(){
            document.getElementById("servicesShow").className = "";
            document.getElementById("servicesShow").className = "servicesHideLink";
    });
    $(".servicesHideLink").click(function(){
            document.getElementById("servicesShow").className = "";
            document.getElementById("servicesShow").className = "servicesShowLink";
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: There is no need to clear the *className* first, you can just set it to the new value. Convert your code to a snippet that shows the behaviour.

Comment: Why use `document` when you are already using jQuery?

Comment: Why not using jQuery ?

Comment: I'd think using jQuery's `toggleClass` would be optimal here if you're already using jQuery

Comment: @RobG change classes or adding a classes? if change it from show to hide and hide to show, i can't do that.

Comment: You are actually changing the class name, after changing the class 'servicesShow', you're trying to get the same class which doesn't exist.

Comment: @clint is that make some differ?

Comment: @AndrewL. idk about toggleClass, can u show me some link?

Comment: document.getElementById('servicesShow').classList.toggle('servicesShowLink')

Then just set it to 'display: none' to start with, and you're good. :)

Comment: @Nimmo thx nimmo... actually i tried to using margin-top:-something to do this because the nav is absolute at top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selectors are evaluated once and produce a set of elements, then the event handler is bound to those element(s), but without knowing anything about the selector you used to get those elements. So even if the classes change, the elements do not, and the event handlers stay like they are.

You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to get what you want:

```
$(document).on('click', ".servicesShowLink", function(){
     $("#servicesShow").removeClass("servicesShow");
     $("#servicesShow").addClass("servicesHideLink");
});
$(document).on('click', ".servicesHideLink", function(){
     $("#servicesShow").removeClass("servicesHideLink");
     $("#servicesShow").addClass("servicesShow");
});
```

I used the opportunity to suggest more jQuery-style code instead of the `document.getElementById` calls, ...etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using `DomElement.classlist.toggle("servicesHideLink");` should solve your problem with one onclick event. I suspect the problem was that when you clicked, it toggled, and added a new event listener, which fired. As such it would make sense to use one event listener.